# Remove duplicate strings in select params array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would know the best way to remove all duplicate strings in select form_tag params.

I tried `.uniq`and `.distinct` but, it doesn't work.

```
<%= select_tag(:city, options_for_select(@customers.where(user: current_user).collect{ |b| [b.city, b.city]}), {:prompt => "City", :class => "form-control select-search"}) %>
```

My `select_tag` gives the cities of each customers even if they have the same.

Comment: Try this `@customers.where(user: current_user).distinct.collect{ |b| [b.city, b.city]}`

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesnt work @Vishal

Comment: Can you share what issue you are facing?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead using `collect` (map) for an ActiveRecord query result, you could use `pluck` this way it returns an array with the selected attributes, and then you can use `uniq`, like:

```
Customer.where(user: current_user).pluck(:city).uniq
# ['city1', 'city2', 'city3']
```

Note pluck and distinct can also go together, it adds the DISTINCT statement to the query and avoid chaining the `uniq` method to its result:

```
Customer.where(user: current_user).pluck('DISTINCT city')
# ['city1', 'city2', 'city3']

Customer.where(user: current_user).distinct.pluck(:city)
# ['city1', 'city2', 'city3']
```

Comment: i tried  "select_tag(:city, options_for_select(Bien.where('user = ?', current_user).pluck('DISTINCT city'))"  and i get a error "operator does not exist: name = integer"